# Live streaming from cctv camera

Tags: ios, objective-c, rtsp, live-streaming

I want to stream from cctv camera when i click on button. I've tried very hard but haven't been able solve it.

The code builds successfully but only a dark screen appears - no stream from the camera.

The code:

```
(IBAction)StreamFromCamera:(id)sender {

NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"rtsp://192.168.1.100/user=admin&password=123&channel=6&stream=0.sdp?"];
   _player=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];
   _player.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 20, self.view.frame.size.width,300);
   [self.view addSubview:_player.view];
   [_player play];

}
```

Comment: How is the camera encoding the video?  Is that format supported by MPMoviePlayer?

Comment: I don't know the code above i saw from the internet.... if you have the code for streming then sed me......

Comment: @Ali : Did u find a solution for this?

Comment: Yes i have done it

Comment: @Ali, would you like to share your solution? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

IOS does not support Rtsp out of the box. You must use, or write, a library to receive the stream and video toolbox to decode and play.

Answer (score 0):

I have been used FFmpeg 2.8 for receiving H.264 data through RTSP protocol and it works well. Let me brief the processing steps:

1. receive RTSP data packet
2. use FFmpeg or Video Toolbox to decode video packet, then render by OpenGL ES which helps us convert YUV to RGB if pixel format of video is yuv format.
3. use FFmpeg to decode audio packet, then use Audio Queue or Audio Unit to play them.

Simple setup code about FFmpeg likes this:

```
AVFormatContext *fmtCtx = avformat_alloc_context();
avformat_open_input(&fmtCtx, server, NULL, &dic);
avformat_find_stream_info(fmtCtx, NULL);
av_dump_format(fmtCtx, 0, NULL, 0);
// find out stream index, sample code:
AVCodecContext *videoCodecCtx = NULL;
int videoStreamIndex = -1;
for (int i = 0 ; i < fmtCtx->nb_streams; i++) {
    if (AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO == fmtCtx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type) {
        videoCodecCtx = fmtCtx->streams[i]->codec;
        videoStreamIndex = i;
        break;
    }
}
AVPacket packet, *pkt = &packet;
// loop av_read_frame and grap AVPacket to Video Toolbox pipeline, 
// data structure transfers like this: 
// AVPacket.data -> CMBlockBuffer -> CMSamplerBuffer -> VTDecompressionDecodeFrame
// get your CVPixelBuffer from Video Toolbox Decode callback function.
```